# Avoiding crash in risk of rain to get the miner character

Tags: risk-of-rain

I'd like to get the miner class in risk of rain, but whenever I go into that area of the magma barracks, it crashes the instant I hit the direseeker/lemurian down there. (in linux)

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Risk of Rain is a very buggy game. It was the dev's first commercial game, and while they did a lot of things right, one of the things they struggled with was getting all of the bugs out. You might be just out of luck.

Comment: You can, however, edit your save file to give yourself access to the Miner: http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Save_values While the community tends to look down on save editing for the sake of cheating, I don't think anyone would fault for for having completed the requirements to unlock a character multiple times but having the game crash on you each time.

Comment: @kevin I guess barring a better alternative, I will do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your save file to give yourself access to the Miner: https://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Save_values

While the community tends to look down on save editing for the sake of cheating, I don't think anyone would fault you for having completed the requirements to unlock a character multiple times but having the game crash on you each time.

(Unfortunately, Risk of Rain is a very buggy game. It was the dev's first commercial game, and while they did a lot of things right, one of the things they struggled with was getting all of the bugs out.)